# How to find where view mode is used for a content type?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

We inherited a site where some content types have several view modes per content types. We are using the out of the box View modes from Drupal 8 and Display Suite is not an option.

How would we find out where each View Mode is used?

Comment: It sounds like a query in the database at the View's Modes table or where else that info is stored.

Comment: @mchar do you have any recommendations on where to look? I have not been able to find any table in the database for this.